# Can I retain 401 certification number along with Developer I?

Tags: certification

Please help me with the maintaining certification number.

I had cleared my Developer 401 exam 4 years back and want to appear for new certifications (Developer I and Developer II). I would like to know if I clear my Developer I certification which is a transition exam. Will I still be able to retain my previous certification number for Developer 401? or Salesforce will provide me new certification number and I would lose my previous credentials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an year from now on you would have both developer and developer 1.In future it will only be developer 1.Salesforce will allocate new license number once you transition.

Comment: Oh that's really unusual. Anyways thanks for the info Mohith. Do you have any link or so where this info has been published so that I can get more information. M willing to take Developer I certification.

Comment: If you have partner portal you will see this notification